# How can I create a Ionic project?

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm following the link [Ionic reference](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)

I have installed node.js v0.12.9.

Then run the command `npm install -g cordova ionic`

Then tried the command `ionic start test_ionic tabs`

I am Working on Windows 7.

I'm getting the following error,

```
C:\Users\prince>ionic start test_ionic tabs
shell.js: internal error
 Error: EBUSY, resource busy or locked 'C:\Users\prince\AppData\Local\Temp\shelljs_758b61ac3625b179c295'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:500:18)
at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1099:15)
at execSync (C:\Users\prince\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\shelljs\src\exec.js:67:57)
at Object._exec (C:\Users\prince\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\shelljs\src\exec.js:179:12)
at Object.exec (C:\Users\prince\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\shelljs\src\common.js:168:23)
at Object.getCordovaInfo (C:\Users\prince\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\info.js:50:24)
at Object.gatherInfo (C:\Users\prince\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\info.js:241:8)
at Object.checkRuntime (C:\Users\prince\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\info.js:288:19)
at Object.doRuntimeCheck (C:\Users\prince\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\cli.js:558:10)
```

Whats wrong with this?

Comment: Looks like it might be a [problem with npm](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7370). You might want to try to upgrade/re-install Node.

Comment: you mentioned working in windows 7. can you tell me where you get above error messages?